# MacBook Pro 13" 2017 GPU spike load

Tags: macbook-pro, gpu, temperature

I have a MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports), Intel Iris Plus Graphics 640 1536 MB, macOS Catalina Version 10.15.5 (but the issue is older).

Sometimes, mostly when I am using Chrome (because this is what I use 80% of the time), but I still don't know if the issue comes only while using Chrome, I get a spike of GPU even if I don't feel that I have done something that demanding...

[image]

The effect is that it start the fan at high speed without "real" reason for 1 minute or so.

Anyone else experiencing this symptom ?

Comment: How can you get a GPU spike when you don’t have one?  Your graphics is *integrated* into the GPU.  The fan comes on when the SMC see’s a *temperature* high enough to spin them up - it’s not limited to load by itself.  What does Activity Monitor say?  What graph are you showing?

Comment: Yes I know this is not literally a GPU but it's related to the video chip inside the CPU, but the peaks comes from the Intel Iris. The graph is from iStat Menu for the Intel Iris

Comment: it’s your CPU.  There’s no separate chip.  The graph is meaningless unless we know what its’ measuring.  What’s “35 on or about June 23rd?”   You also ignored my question re: activity monitor because CPU load isn’t the only factor..  You’ve got temperature which is more than just the CPU temp.

Comment: You are right, I thought that this graph (Load average from iStat Menu) was for the "GPU" because it's below but it is not at all ! https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193580/how-does-one-interpret-load-average-in-istat-menus  |  So there is nothing wrong with my Intel Iris if I look at the right graphic. For example today, I got a peak of Load average when I started streaming something on the Chromecast, but this was 30% average (over 1min) which mean a little more than 1 CPU at 100%. So I suppose nothing is weird after all... ?

Comment: The question is..."in relation to what?"  You can't say something is/isn't weird with nothing to compare it to.  30% may be high (I don't use Chrome because it's a resource hog) or it may be right in line with what you're doing.  Having the fan come on is not an indication of anything other than the SMC needs to cool things down.

Comment: Related to the 30% it's over a 1min period : waking up from sleep the laptop and using Airflow to stream a BDRip movie :)

Comment: You are streaming a BD movie and wonder about *PU spikes and fan noise?